# How to make a Smart Light Bulb?

Tags: led, bluetooth

I was wondering what I would need and what I should do, to make a **Smart Light Bulb**, like the [Hue one](http://www2.meethue.com/it-it/) from Philips.

1. I know these light bulbs can be **controlled** by their **Apps** from the smartphone, is there a way I can achieve this too?
2. What **components** would I need to purchase?
3. Is there a reference or a tutorial on how I should **program** this light bulb?

Comment: What has this got to do with the Arduino? I'm going to close this question. Feel free to edit it with new information. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!

Comment: This is a question of how to achieve this with Arduino, that's why I posted it here @NickGammon

Comment: Which Arduino were you planning to insert into the light bulb? Your question is still incredibly broad. You may as well say "I would like to fly to the moon - is there a way I can achieve this?". `What components would I need to purchase?` - well, a light bulb and an Arduino? This sounds like you are trying to get us to do a project for you, sorry.

Comment: I asked what to start with, if you got it in that way I'm sorry as It isn't meant to be that. @NickGammon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an ESP8266 NODEMCU. There is an example for making it emulate a Hue bridge ( https://github.com/probonopd/ESP8266HueEmulator ). 
To have the official bridge control your lights would take Zigbee and finding out the protocol that Philips uses. Their API is open source, however the zigbee protocol they use is not afaik.
ESP8266 is a very cheap solution that works with arduino ide and does not need an arduino. There are powerplugs which have an ESP8266 in them (https://www.itead.cc/smart-home/sonoff-sv.html)

Comment: Mh cool, thank you, will have a look at it tomorrow morning and then will let you know :)

Comment: Oh, so this would work with iOS too right? I mean, the bulb would be then controllable by the iOS hue app? Or not?

Comment: yes it will work with any Hue app !! so also on iOS :)

Comment: oh when getting an esp8266.. make sure it is esp8266-12e. the older ones only have 2 outputs and very limited compared to the newer model. you be up and running for around $10.

Comment: Oh, and the light bulbs, how should I make them? I mean the first link is for the hub, the second one for the light bulb?

Comment: yep :) the second link is esp8266 with a relais connected to a gpio port, you can load the bridge software on there or get a seperate esp8266 to play bridge and get more bulbs to listen to your Leonardo Hue ....

Comment: Alright! Will get to work asap and will let you know! So for now this is the right answer, thank you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42152/discussion-between-coffeeholic-and-leonardo).